# jQuery checkbox count when selected

Tags: jquery

I have four checkboxes. I need to check if atleast 2 are selected. They are not inside any DIV.They are independent. Form will be submitted only when atleast 2 checkboxes are selected.

Comment: Please post an HTML snippet as well as a jQuery snippet showing what you've already tried.

Comment: `$('.checkboxes:checked').length > 1`

Comment: there are checkboxes at other section also.So cannot directly use it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
<form id="submitForm" method="POST">

<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" id="checkboxname" value="check1"> check1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" id="checkboxname" value="check2"> check2
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" id="checkboxname" value="check3"> check3
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" id="checkboxname" value="check4"> check4

<input type="submit" name="proceed" value="proceed" id="proceed">
</form>
```

and the jquery script is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#proceed').click(function(){
        alert('im triggered')
        alert($('#checkboxname:checked').length)
    });

});
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery Playground</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Submit Form</h1>
    <p>Select two options below and submit form</p>
    <form action="action.php" method="post" id="myForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <p>Select only 2 fruits you would like to have for dinner</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="orange" class="fruit"> Oranges<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="banana" class="fruit"> Bananas<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" class="fruit"> Apples<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="grape" class="fruit"> Grape<br>
        <input id="go" type="submit" value="Go Button">
    </form>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ){

            $("#myForm").on( "submit", function( e ){

                // check if 2 items have been checked                    
                if( $(".fruit:checked").length !== 2 ){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
                // continue form submission if 2 items have been checked
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
```